# missing host information when running ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have an ansbile.cfg file as well as a host file in a directory. In the same directory, I have a test_playbook.yml file.  All three are copied below.  When I run the ping (ad-hoc) command, I get a successful response.  However, when I try running the ansible-playbook command, the response states the following:

```
     [WARNING]: Host file not found: testserver

     [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available

skipping: no hosts matched
```

**ansible.cfg**

```
[defaults]
hostfile = hosts
remote_user = testuser
##private_key_file = .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
##host_key_checking = False
```

**hosts**

```
[webservers]
testserver ansible_ssh_host=ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com ansible_ssh_port=1234
```

**test_playbook.yml**

```
   ---
    - hosts: all
      remote_user: testuser
      become: yes
      become_user: testuser
      tasks: 
      - group: 
           name: devops
           state: present
      - name: create devops user with admin privileges

        user: 
          name: devops
          comment: "Devops User"
          uid: 2001
          groups: devops
```

The command that I am running is the following:

```
ansible-playbook test_playbook.yml -i testserver -vvv
```

**response:**

Any idea on what I might have misconfigured?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`-i` specifies your inventory file, not the host. So it should be `-i hosts`.

```
ansible-playbook test_playbook.yml -i hosts
```

You also can directly pass the host, but then you won't have the behavioral host vars as defined in the inventory file:

```
ansible-playbook test_playbook.yml -i testserver,
```

The `,` makes ansible treat it as a list of hosts, otherwise it will treat it as a filename.

If you want to limit it to the host `testserver` you can work with the `--limit` option

```
ansible-playbook test_playbook.yml -i hosts --limit testserver
```

Comment: will accept as soon as SO allows me to - thanks.  I needed to specify the inventory file name, not the servername specified in the host file